# dojox.mobile.SimpleDialog is not modal

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, dojo, dojox.mobile, worklight-studio

I have the following structure of the Worklight application page:

```
<body>
    <div with heading/>
    <div with view/>
    <div with Tab bar/>
    <div with simple dialog/>
</body>
```

When I build the app for iPad and test it on it i have the following problem.
Dialog window puts gray unclickable layer on everything except the tab bar.

Why the tab bar stays available?

Is it a bug or I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried put in views in a different variations, but it still didn't work.

Than while debugging I found out that the grey cover, which should cover everything in background has a

```
postion: absolute;
```

than I override this css class with

```
position: fixed;
```

and everything became great:)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to put the heading, tab bar and dialog in the view?

Answer (score 0):

Who invoke simpleDialog? try this

```
        <body> 
           <div id="home" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.ScrollableView"
                    data-dojo-props='selected:true'>
               <div with heading/>
              <div with simple dialog

<button data-dojo-type='dojox.mobile.Button' onClick="openDialog()">

/>
              <div with Tab bar/>
            </div>
        </body>
```

for invoke simple dialog, write

```
function openDialog(){
    WL.SimpleDialog.show("text ", "text",[{text: "buttonName", handler: function() {WL.Logger.debug("dfsdfd"); }
                }]
}
            );
```